# How use Laravel Mail facade outside app folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

i do a script on root of my site. This script is lauch by cron.
At the end of script, i try to send mail with the result of process by use Mail facade laravel, but it doens't work.

On the top of my script i put this:

```
 require_once('../../vendor/autoload.php');
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

and call

`Mail::send(...)`

but i have "a facade root has not been set".

Thanks for your help

Edit:
I add theses lines

```
require __DIR__.'/../' . 'bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../' . 'bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

$kernel->handle(;
  $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

for replace

```
require_once('../../vendor/autoload.php');
```

Now i have no error message, but I don't receive the mail

Someone can help me

Comment: remove required it is not needed as because use method is does same thing

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I removed 'require_once('../../vendor/autoload.php');', but i have a same error

Answer (score 0):

Facades are called statically, so try
`Mail::send();`

Laravel facades serve as "static proxies" to underlying classes in the service container, providing the benefit of a terse, expressive syntax while maintaining more testability and flexibility than traditional static methods. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades